# Python Regular Expression - Won't match values after '='

Tags: python, regex, expression, match

I have a input file that is formatted like so:

[CATEGORY]=value
[CATEGORY2]=value2

I am using a regular expression to match each "Category" and each "Value" in the input file. The category regular expression works correctly but I am now trying to get the value that follows that category tag. I am trying to match "=value" so I made the following regular expression below:

```
for inputLine in configFile:
     x = re.match('=.+', inputLine)
```

The issue is that every time I check the value of the variable 'x', it is of type "None" so I know the regular expression is not working. I've narrowed it down to the '=' sign not correctly working in the expression. I've printed out the inputLine and it prints [CATEGORY]=value so I know that is correctly reading the file.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: After you match the category, do you change the string so it starts with '='? If not then you should be using `re.search` instead. `re.match` starts from the beginning of the provided string.

Comment: Ah that's why! the start of my string technically would be [CATEGORY] since my string is the whole line. I don't change the string in any way so re.search works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for inputLine in configFile:
    x = re.search('=.+', inputLine)
```

And you should get what you're looking for.